# Can't connect Arduino to RFID

Tags: arduino, ide, serial-port, rfid

I am using an A-Star 32U4 Micro Arduino and I'm trying to connect the RDM6300 - 125KHz Cardreader Mini-Module.

I'm using this sketch at the moment:

```cpp
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

// RFID  | Nano
// Pin 1 | D2
// Pin 2 | D3
SoftwareSerial Rfid = SoftwareSerial(2,3);

void setup() {
  // Serial Monitor to see results on the computer
  Serial.begin(9600);
  // Communication to the RFID reader
  Rfid.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  // check, if any data is available
  if(Rfid.available() > 0 ){
    // as long as there is data available...
    while(Rfid.available() > 0 ){
      // read a byte
      int r = Rfid.read();
      // print it to the serial monitor
      Serial.print(r, DEC);
      Serial.print(" ");
    }
    // linebreak
    Serial.println();
  }
}
```

With this circuit:

- module TX --- Arduino pin 2
- module VCC ----- 5v
- module  ground ---- ground
- antenna pins ---- antenna

When I put the card in the sensor nothing shows up on serial port. I tried this setup and the exact same sensors on an Arduino Uno (same sketch) and it worked perfectly, but I cant get this working on the Micro.

Comment: Why use software serial if you have hardware serial available?

Comment: how can i use it?

Comment: Hardware serial (pins 0 and 1) is accessible with  `Serial1`.

Answer (score 1):

Arduino UNO and Micro uses different processors, though they work fairly similarly, they are not totaly identical.

It seams that

> not all pins on the Leonardo and Micro support change interrupts, so only the following can be used for RX: 8, 9, 10, 11, 14 (MISO), 15 (SCK), 16 (MOSI).

From the SoftwareSerial Library description ( https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/softwareSerial )

Change the module TX from pin 2 to pin 8. and you should be good. :-)

Comment: If you are happy with the solution, could you be so kind as to mark the answer as accepted, please.